# Form submit with radio input

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

I have a form with radio input
 Questions
Choose Yes or No for either:

Question 1   Yes No
Question 2  Yes No
Question 3   Yes No
Question 4  Yes No
Question 5   Yes No
Question 6  Yes No

I have the validation working already using JQuery Validation Plugin. The valdation just check to make sure a question answer is selected.

So once no for anyone is selected...it must go to the no.html..if yes is selected for any...it must go to the no.html

Now what I want is this:

I want if a user selects Yes for any question, once they selects Yes, I want it to direct me to a Yes.html Page

and if they selects No for any question, direct me to a No.html page.

That's it.

Comment: best approach with the syntax

Comment: So you're saying...  I'm presented with *N* questions, with a Yes or No choice for each. As soon as I pick either a Yes or a No for *any* of the questions I leave the page; that is, I don't pick answers for all of the questions?

Comment: yes u have to pick all the answers, but the most important part is...once you click a yes, u **must** go to the yes.html page

Comment: Once there's a yes, it must go to the yes.html

Comment: You're still saying two things that are in conflict: 1. You have to pick all the answers. 2. Once there's a yes it must go to yes.html --- if it goes to yes.html as soon as you pick a Yes, you won't have a chance to answer the other questions.

Comment: no no, we are talking about after all is selected. i already have a validation in place to make sure all selection is made. now just looking for an if statement to say if yes is selected, then go to yes.html....else go to no.html

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something you should be handling on the server side, rather than with JavaScript.  Here's how I'd approach it:

Use check boxes in the form, rather than radio buttons.  That way, you don't need validation, as there's no way to submit a "blank" answer:  If you get a value submitted for a check box, it was checked (YES), otherwise it wasn't (NO).

Then in the server script that handles the input from that form, check to see if any of the question had YES answers.  If they did, redirect to yes.html; otherwise, redirect to no.html.

Hope this helps!

**Edit:**  If you must do this client-side, you can do it with something like this (HTML):

```
<form id="myform">
    <ul>
        <li><input name="check1" value="1" />Question 1</li>
        <li><input name="check2" value="1" />Question 2</li>
        <li><input name="check3" value="1" />Question 3</li>
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" value="Click Me!" />
</form>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
    $(this).attr('action', ($(this).find('input:checked').length)? 'yes.html' : 'no.html');
});
```

When the form is about to be submitted, the JS looks for checked inputs (YES answers) and changes the target (or 'action') of the form to the correct page.  If there are any, the form goes to the 'yes.html' page - otherwise, it goes to 'no.html'.

Comment: i want to handle it client side, can u help?

Comment: @user634599  I've added client-side code into my answer - take a look!